# Selecting Between Hours with Timestamp in SQL

Tags: sql, oracle

I need to figure out how I can select the AVG from another column in a table, between two hour time intervals. I am using PL/SQL/Serverpages or PSP, so the user would select their interval of choice from a drop down menu (ex "2PM-4PM, 4PM-6PM",etc.) and then on the second page, using their choice I will provide information from another column in the table. The issue I have is that the format of my timestamp column is:

```
30-OCT-16 02.52.00.000000000 PM
30-OCT-16 02.54.00.000000000 PM
```

The way I have been trying to solve this problem is by using the following methodology:

IF number_text = 1 THEN

```
SELECT AVG(column) INTO avg_power
FROM table
WHERE date_column BETWEEN TO_DATE('12','HH') AND TO_DATE('2','HH')
AND LIKE '%PM';
```

I am going to use various IF statements in order to activate each select statement with the IF contingent on which interval the user selects from a drop down list.

As I said, the variable time depends on what the user selects on a prior page. My biggest issues in this situation are figuring out how I am supposed to code the WHERE clause as well as finding a way to work with the data, in terms of hours, as it exists in the database, while also taking AM and PM into account. I greatly appreciate any and all help to solve this issue.

Comment: `where table_date between thevariabletime and thevariabletime + interval '2' hour` might be a simpler way of writing your WHERE clause, though it will depend on the datatype of `thevariabletime`. Also when you say the format of your datetime column is `30-OCT-16 02.52.00.000000000 PM` do you mean the datatype is `timestamp`?

Comment: Yes, the datatype is timestamp. I will also provide an update to what I have.

Comment: Still would love any and all nelp, @WilliamRobertson